# Returns wrong frame while seeking in FFMPEG Player

Tags: android, ffmpeg, audio-player

I have implemented an audio player which supports all the formats using FFMPEG. But while seeking the audio, the application is getting the wrong frame at that target duration. Here is my code for the seek functionality.

```
         int64_t seekTime = av_rescale_q(seekValue * AV_TIME_BASE,
                    AV_TIME_BASE_Q,
                    fmt_ctx->streams[seekStreamIndex]->time_base);

            int64_t seekStreamDuration =
                    fmt_ctx->streams[seekStreamIndex]->duration;

            int flags = AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD;
            if (seekTime > 0 && seekTime < seekStreamDuration)
                flags |= AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY;

            int ret = av_seek_frame(fmt_ctx, seekStreamIndex, seek_target,
                    flags);

            if (ret < 0)
                ret = av_seek_frame(fmt_ctx, seekStreamIndex, seekTime,
                        flags);

          avcodec_flush_buffers(dec_ctx);
```

It is working fine for most of the songs.
But some of the mp3 songs are getting the wrong timespan.

For instance: If the song total duration is 2 minutes, if I play the song without seeking it works fine. But while playing, if we seek the song to some position, this will make the song ends with 2 mins and 10 seconds.

I am getting this issue with only mp3 songs. I am using FFMPEG 2.1. The code for the seek functionality is working fine on FFMPEG 0.11.1.

Please provide any information about this issue.